# sequence diagram using latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-umlsd

I want to draw sequence diagram like below:

[image]

This is my code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: clean1
% arara: clean: { files: [ Commands.aux , .main.ptd , TP.aux] }
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[a3paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{ultramarine}{rgb}{0.91, 1.0, 1.0}

\begin{document}

  \centering
    \scalebox{1}
    {  \begin{sequencediagram}
    \newthread{A}{\shortstack{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [fill=ultramarine,draw=black,thick ,align=center] {A };
\end{tikzpicture}}}
    \newinst{B}{\shortstack{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [fill=ultramarine,draw=black,thick ,align=center] {B };
\end{tikzpicture}}}
    \newinst{C}{\shortstack{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [fill=ultramarine,draw=black,thick ,align=center] {C };
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\begin{messcall}{A}{ A2B }{B}
 \end{messcall}

\begin{messcall}{B}{B2C }{C}
\end{messcall}
  \end{sequencediagram}
  }
\end{document}
```

and output:
[image]

Comment: See [TeXample.net: UML sequence diagrams](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pgf-umlsd/) or [Drawing UML Sequence Diagram by using pgf-umlsd](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-umlsd/pgf-umlsd-manual.pdf)

Comment: They do not contain my goal!

Comment: I want rectangle below C to be gray and line B2C Sticks below rectangle B

Comment: I think that `pgf-umlsd` can't do this out of the box. `messcall` has an optional argument that allows you to shorten the box. Something like `\begin{messcall}[0]{A}{A2B}{B}
\begin{messcall}{B}{B2C}{C}
\end{messcall}
\end{messcall}` is a bit closer to want you depicted.

Comment: Nesting `tikzpicture`s is unsupported and liable to break. It should be avoided.